Black formatter for Python gives a decoding error "not a utf-8 character" - how can I tell black to use 'UTF-16'?
NONE of the suggestions to get the file into utf-8 succeeded.
In desperation, I switched from black to ruff.py and am proceeding.
ruff had no trouble with the directory of files.
intelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 has an option in settings to set encoding to utf-8
with that option set, the result from black is unchanged
I added a magic header:
-- coding: utf-8 --
no change in the results
input file is created by intelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2
Several files give the same error.
I see comments suggesting that utf-8 is standard encoding
and trusted that intelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 would mind the standard.
I removed the --diff  tag, but still got the same results.
on windows 11, with python 3.11
trying to format any of my python.py files
I get this traceback
FINAL line says:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

E:\python\Projects\p2>python -m black --diff settings.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\black\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    patched_main()
  File "src\black\__init__.py", line 1602, in patched_main
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src\black\__init__.py", line 668, in main
  File "src\black\__init__.py", line 744, in get_sources
  File "C:\Users\dickr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\black\files.py", line 254, in get_gitignore
    lines = gf.readlines()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

I've searched black documentation for an option to change encoding with no luck.
google searched for the problem as it relates to black

UTF-16 is not a valid Python source file encoding.  See PEP 263.  Note: In Python 3 the default source encoding was changed to UTF-8 from ASCII, but other rules for allowed encodings apply.

PEP 3120 documents the default source encoding change from ASCII to UTF-8.

Black probably reads the source the same way the Python engine does...by checking for the #coding: encoding declaration and otherwise assuming UTF-8.

Probably the path of least resistance is to convert your files to UTF-8 before you begin.  Just think of it as one more formatting change you're imposing.

The magic header won't make a difference if that isn't the actual encoding being used by the file.  The answer is to fix all your files.


How can I tell black to use 'UTF-16'?

You can't. Instead:

Convert your file to utf-8.
Use black.
Convert back.

In Linux you would do something along iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 input | black - | iconv -f UTF8 -f UTF16 | sponge input.

Or rather: 0. set up IntelliJ to use UTF-8 and omit step 3.
